# Converting MySQL Prepared statement into php code

Tags: mysql

I've the following the following MySQL Prepared Statement courtesy of @jpw. The query works fine. You can checkout the working query on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7185e/8) but I just can't convert this prepared statement into php code. I need help for it.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(gender = ''',
      gender,
      ''' and r.name = ''',
      r.name, ''') AS "',
      if(gender='m','Male','Female'), ' ', r.name, '" '
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  tbl_user u
JOIN 
  tbl_religion r ON u.religion = r.id;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'select timestampdiff(year, dob, now()) age, ', @sql, ' 
  from tbl_user u
  join tbl_religion r on u.religion = r.id
  group by timestampdiff(year, dob, now());');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Make a stored proc out of it

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i can think of is to use  **[ Create PHP Code ]** option if you use Phpmyadmin.

or You could use Sql formatting service like http://sqlformat.org/ or http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm. to quickly format SQL to php or any language.
Ofcourse there could be other better ways of achieving this.

Here is your example formatted through sqlformat.org

```
<?php
$sql = " ";
$sql .= "SET @sql = NULL;";
$sql2  = " ";
$sql2 .= "
 ";
$sql2 .= "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'sum(gender = ''', gender, ''' and r.name = ''', r.name, ''') AS \"', if(gender='m','Male','Female'), ' ', r.name, '\" ' ) ) INTO @sql ";
$sql2 .= "FROM tbl_user u ";
$sql2 .= "JOIN tbl_religion r ON u.religion = r.id;";
$sql3  = " ";
$sql3 .= "
  ";
$sql3 .= "SET @sql = CONCAT( 'select timestampdiff(year, dob, now()) age, ', @sql, ' 
  from tbl_user u
  join tbl_religion r on u.religion = r.id
  group by timestampdiff(year, dob, now());');";
$sql4  = " ";
$sql4 .= "
 PREPARE stmt ";
$sql4 .= "FROM @sql;";
$sql5 = " ";
$sql5 .= "
 EXECUTE stmt;";
$sql6 = " ";
$sql6 .= "
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";
$sql7 = " ";
$sql7 .= "
 ";

echo "$sql$sql2$sql3$sql4$sql5$sql6$sql7";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur effort. But I still can't work it out. I need the result in an array. Can u help me further.